# Creating nested list from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I am having trouble doing a nested list from a dictionary. I wish anyone can help me to achieve my goal output, you can see it at the bottom.

My code:

```
data = {
    "abc": [{"cba": "cab", "lmn": "mnl"}],
    "def": [{"fed": "fde", "opq": "poq", "rst": "tsr", "jkl": "klj"}],
    "ghi": [{"xyz": "zxy", "uvw": "vuw"}],
    "etag": "W/ABCDXYZ"
}

dict_list = []
dict_lists = []

for d in data.keys():
    dict_obj = {}
    if isinstance(data[d], list):
        for dl in data[d]:
            dict_obj[d] = dl
            dict_list.append(dict_obj)
    else:
        dict_list.append({d : data[d]})

for dl in dict_list:
    dict_obj = {}
    for do in dl:
        if isinstance(dl[do], dict):
            for v in dl[do].keys():
                dict_obj[do] = { v : dl[do][v] }
                dict_lists.append({ do : dict_obj[do] })
        else:
            dict_lists.append([{ do : dl[do] }])

print(dict_lists)
```

Output

```
[{'abc': {'cba': 'cab'}}, {'abc': {'lmn': 'mnl'}}, 
{'def': {'fed': 'fde'}}, {'def': {'opq': 'poq'}}, {'def': {'rst': 'tsr'}}, {'def': {'jkl': 'klj'}}, 
{'ghi': {'xyz': 'zxy'}}, {'ghi': {'uvw': 'vuw'}}, 
[{'etag': 'W/ABCDXYZ'}]]
```

My goal is to achieve the output below.

```
[
[{'abc': {'cba': 'cab'}}, {'abc': {'lmn': 'mnl'}}], 
[{'def': {'fed': 'fde'}}, {'def': {'opq': 'poq'}}, {'def': {'rst': 'tsr'}}, {'def': {'jkl': 'klj'}}], 
[{'ghi': {'xyz': 'zxy'}}, {'ghi': {'uvw': 'vuw'}}], 
[{'etag': 'W/ABCDXYZ'}]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do the job:

```
out = []
for key, values in data.items():
    lst = []
    if type(values[0]) != dict:
        lst.append({key: values[0]})
    else:
        for k, v in values[0].items():
            lst.append({key: {k: v}})
    out.append(lst)

print(out)
```

Here is the output:

```
[
 [{'abc': {'cba': 'cab'}}, {'abc': {'lmn': 'mnl'}}],
 [{'def': {'fed': 'fde'}}, {'def': {'opq': 'poq'}}, {'def': {'rst': 'tsr'}}, {'def': {'jkl': 'klj'}}],
 [{'ghi': {'xyz': 'zxy'}}, {'ghi': {'uvw': 'vuw'}}],
 [{'etag': 'W/ABCDXYZ'}]
]
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help ;)